# Load Google Maps marker from the div id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps, real-time

Firstl,y I am new in world for Stack Overflow and jQuery, sorry for my mistakes.
I tried to make a simple realtime Google Maps marker in my website to reload an id every 1 second and they are Lat, Long for Google Maps. But when I tried  JavaScript, it said invalid value. I tried to put in alert but everything looks ok.

ERROR look like this

> InvalidValueError: setPosition: not a LatLng or LatLngLiteral: not an Object

```
function moveMarker( map, marker ) {

  setInterval( function() { 
    //Reload new lat long to id 
    $("#container12").load(" #container1");    
    //Load data from id 
    var uluru = document.getElementById("container1");
    //Filter for all HTML  and put only Lat, Long
    textContent = uluru.textContent;
    //put the Marker to google map
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: textContent, map: map});
    //test if data ar loaded fine  or loock eveything ok like "11.12, 13.14"
    alert(textContent);
    //Run this every second
  }, 1000 );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not passing a latLng object to the position. Pass a javascript object like the code below

```
var uluru = document.getElementById("container1");
var pos = uluru.innerHTML.split(',');
pos = {Number(pos[0].trim()),Number(pos[1].trim())};
```

That would mean you will need to check the value `textContent` that you've passed. You code should then look as below.

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: pos, map: map});
```

Comment: first thx for anser i tray to load textContent from  <a id=Container>lat, Long</a> bicos the lat long change every seond i can not put only 1 lat long thets load automaticly  its everytime diferent

Comment: I have edited the code to address specifically your comment

Comment: no thets dont work the same error  the problem is  the lat long is ok bicos i test it with alert and work fine  but when the point is to load like marker in google maps don't work

Comment: check the reference to the map object

Comment: o i am sory i dont add it hier  <div id="map-canvas" style="width:100%;height:400px;"></div>
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=myapikey&sensor=false"></script>

Comment: Do you need to show all previous markers? If no just render the map with the new marker again

Comment: no thets like GPS tracker the data refresh every second in <a id=container1>(refreshed lat long)<a> and this lat long to put in google map every second but thets don't work